# How can I drag an element into a dropdown list using jQuery UI sortable()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

**Short version**: How can I drag `Link 1` into one of the dropdowns under `Link 3` in this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/Gdadu/2/

**EDIT**: The issue has been brought up about what should happen when an item is dragged over another: should it be placed to the left/right or start a new submenu? In order for the list to be fully sortable, there has to be some way to drop items into non-existing submenus, starting a new `ul` dropdown. I could insert an empty `ul` in every list item that doesn't have one yet to serve as a drop target, but the problem above still exists.

This seems a lot more difficult than I initially thought, so I apologize for not having put more effort into this yet, as I hadn't considered some of these problems. I'm willing to accept an answer to the stated issue and worry about the rest later.

---

I have a basic dropdown navigation list that I want to be fully sortable, using jQuery UI. Any `li` element should be able to move to any position in the entire list. I'm having trouble with dragging top level list items into submenus, it seems that `:hover` doesn't trigger on the dropdown list while in "drag mode", so the dropdowns don't appear.

Example HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.dropdown,
.dropdown li,
.dropdown ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.dropdown {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    z-index:10000;
}
.dropdown ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width:100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    display:none;
    z-index:900;
}
.dropdown ul ul {
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}
.dropdown li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.dropdown li:hover{
    z-index:910;
    cursor:default;
}
.dropdown ul:hover,
.dropdown li:hover > ul,
.dropdown a:hover + ul,
.dropdown a:focus + ul {
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
}
.dropdown a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:.5em 2em;
    background:#cde;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown ul li {
    width:100%;
}
```

Sortable initialization:

```
$('.dropdown').sortable({
    items: 'li'
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdadu/2/

For example, I want to drag "Link 1" into a submenu, but can't do it because the submenu doesn't appear while dragging, as if `:hover` is ignored. I'm not sure if the problem lies in the CSS or javascript. What can I do about this?

Good idea from the comments:

> Perhaps you could trigger everything to expand when a drag starts

This would probably work, but I don't want the entire menu to expand. It could be a lot of content with many links and 3 levels of navigation, and would probably overlap itself with all the flyouts/dropdowns (huge mess).

Comment: If you're dragging something, you are hovering over what you are dragging, which is blocking the item beneath it...

Comment: We're still hovering over multiple elements, look here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdadu/4/ The `html:hover` is still triggered. In any case, I'm looking for a solution to the stated problem.

Comment: That's only because it's already active before you drag.  No new hovers will be triggered while dragging.  Perhaps you could trigger everything to expand when a drag starts.

Comment: awesome coding mate. I really like what you did in this code.

Comment: as far as I know html has :hover always triggered because it has the elements in it. So if you have 'a' element and 'b' is child of 'a' than if you hover over 'b', 'a' will also have the :hover state

hope I helped.

Comment: Since your list is sortable, the Link 3 menu moves out of the way when dragging Link 1, so you never hover over Link 3 and hence never open the menu. You could try some code to check while dragging the sortable if the placeholder is immediately after a hover menu, open the menu.... might be a lot of work tho.

Comment: What you want to achieve won't be easy, mostly because jQuery UI's sortable widget is not (yet) prepared to deal with a pure CSS cascading menu. As others have said, a drag operation is usually supposed to capture mouse events in the first place, not to relay them to the element "actually" under the cursor. This basically defeats the `:hover` rule. So far, even [some CSS trickery](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdadu/9/) to expand the next menu when hovering over the sortable's placeholder still does not consider the expanded menu items as sortable drop sites.

Comment: Seems to me you have a logical problem. Since you say every li should be able to be dragged to any position, what should happen when you move item1 over item2: Exchange their places in the top level list, or nest item1 under item2 as submenu entry number 1?

Comment: That's pretty clever @Frédéric, I think you may be on to something. Kontur: Since Link 2 doesn't have a submenu, I would expect Link 1 to be placed on either side of Link 2, but now I see what you mean - no way to start a new dropdown where there wasn't one to begin with... I wonder what can be done about this, I'll have to do some more testing as this isn't as simple as I initially thought it would be.

Comment: @Madmartigan, well, calling the `refresh` method from the `change` event should update the sortable widget with the newly visible elements, and apparently it does because [now the menu collapses when the placeholder is removed](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdadu/10/)... so we're back to square one. Besides hacking jQuery UI to support CSS menus, did you consider expanding all your menu items on drag start? This can be achieved with further CSS trickery, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Frédéric: Yes, one of the earlier comments suggested this, but it would be a gigantic mess having every item shown at once, and many would overlap. I was trying to avoid the "backend" UI for this (which doesn't use dropdowns) and have more control over this stuff right from the front end, but as I'm starting to become aware of more issues (namely, starting *new* sub menus as brought up by kontur) I might just give up.

Comment: Indeed, things would actually be simpler if your cascading menu was entirely script-driven. I understand pure CSS implementations are very attractive and indeed bear many advantages, but I'm afraid the UI you want to build is too sophisticated to incorporate that without a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that shows a few points that can help you with your implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdadu/13/

It is far from perfect, and as pointed out in the comment, there is a few logical problems also with "sorting everything everywhere" :) Things not working here are sorting nested li's back to top level, sortables on nested ul's, ... but I think they are sketched out there. Distinguishing the sorting from the dragging might be one thing necessairy with jqueryui's current status. Also I shortcut your excellent css solution for the submenus and made them javascript based as to simplify things a bit.

But: You can drop link1 inside link3 or link3's nested ul ;)

Comment: I'm looking at this, trying to make something useful out of it. I'll let you know how I make out tomorrow night.

Comment: Other commitments caused me to leave this task behind for probably the next 2 months, so I'm giving this the checkmark as promised. Thanks for the brave attempt, if I ever get back to this I'll be sure to post my final solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Had a similar problem once where I'd designed a CMS interface, where you could "live" edit the navigation while browsing the site as admin. Using 'helper buttons' for different tasks like drag&drop or sort was, from a usability standpoint, the clearest solution.

Comment: I started going in the direction of "click to edit -> change CSS class so it's easier to manage (not a dropdown) -> change back when done". I've found that drag/drop sorting really needs a "Save" button to make up for messy mistakes rather than updating on every drop. This ensures the changes are all committed at once as well.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Oft the technical more simple solution is also easier for the user to understand, even if a more slick technical solution could be implemented :)

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124219/reputation-events-like-accept-unaccept-can-occur-too-frequently

Comment: @keith, does your comment/link have anything to do with the topic or answer?

Comment: Someone used your answer in a (harmless) experiment of the new reputation handling code. Take a look at your reputation history (click your score at the top of the page); you'll see several hundred points added and subtracted. It's nothing to worry about, but I thought you might like to know what's going on.