# Simple CSS Dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made a few attempts at this and they ended up just getting confusing.  The current HTML and CSS seems to be working fine for a simple horizontal CSS menu.  I am struggling with dropping subitems off the current `<li>` elements.

I am trying to making them show up exactly below the current menu items with the same hovering effects as I have in place now.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  I am admittedly no CSS pro.

Current HTML:

```
<div class="MenuTop">
    <ul class="Nav">
    <li><a href="Home.aspx" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Vehicles.aspx" title="Vehicles">Vehicles</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="SubItem.aspx" title="SubOne">SubItemOne</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="About.aspx" title="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.aspx" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="News.aspx" title="News">News</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Current CSS:

```
.MenuTop
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: Black;
    color: #fff;
    margin: auto auto 0px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    height:auto;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    min-height:15px;
}
.MenuTop ul
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: -5px ;
    padding: 0px;
}
.MenuTop li 
{
    float: left;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.MenuTop a 
{
    background-color: Black;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.MenuTop a:hover 
{
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px;
}
```

Comment: There's s problem with your current HTML: There are no sub items. There's nothing to "drop down" and if there were, you haven't attempted to write any styles for it.

Comment: I tried several times and it caused more issues than it helped.  I removed it so it would be a fresh start.  I can edit it, but I figured this would be simpler.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: There I added one.  I could be going about this all wrong, but I have no idea how to implement it.  Most of the examples I have seen on the web that are decent are trying to monetize off of their stuff.

Comment: Look up superfish. Excellent plugin that does this for you. I'm on mobile or I'd fix your code

Comment: A lot of examples on the web are still trying to support IE6 as well. You can steal my code from this post if you want, but it looks like Andres has you covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134490/how-can-i-drag-an-element-into-a-dropdown-list-using-jquery-ui-sortable

Comment: Also, this link: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you're forgetting about positioning your submenu items absolutely to your parent `li` menu item and hiding it as well, by using `display:none` and then showing it on hover, so try something like this to achieve that effect:

**CSS**

```
.Nav li {
    position:relative;
}

.Nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}

.Nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Also, your submenu `ul` is not properly closed so go ahead and close it.

Ninja Edit: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gKHDR/5/), by the way you can greatly benefit from properly targeting your menu by using the class you have given it, `.Nav`, instead of its parent class of its container, `.MenuTop`, that way you can target your menu and your menu alone and not any other element you might place inside that container,

Comment: That worked great.  One issue remains.  The subitems will appear behind the content below them.  I want them to always be on top.  Is this a z-index thing?  Figured that part out... Thanks again

Comment: @Matt yes, that is a `z-index` issue, you can fix that by adding `z-index:9999` to your submenu items, `.Nav li ul`, and a property of `position:relative` with a lower z-index ( e.g `z-index:1;` ) to your content container.

Comment: The dropdown doesn't seem to persist when you mouse over newly-appeared items... if you make the <li> the hoverable item rather than the <a> in the top menu you can keep everything persisent with pure CSS.

Comment: @rfinz focused on the dropdown portion of the question but that is due to the margin/padding of the `a` element. Cleaned it up and now it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gKHDR/5/

Comment: @Matt cleaned up the code for your menu so use my latest demo instead (added a few things also, like clearfix).

Comment: @Matt that is how it works by default but you can go beyond that and make the long menu items stay in one line by using something like `white-space:pre`, here is a demo with some long menu items: http://jsfiddle.net/gKHDR/6/

Comment: @Andres:  I tried using whitespace.  Didn't have any luck.  I have an updated JSFiddle here.  Can you see what the issue is?  http://jsfiddle.net/5enYP/

Comment: @Matt you're declaring two different styles for your menu by using the `.MenuTop li` and `.Nav li` class, so you're targeting your menu twice with two different sets of styles. The submenu is appearing as it is because you're floating left your `a` elements and also your `li` elements, we only need floated the first level menu items, which is why use use this `.Nav > li { float: left; }`, notice the greater than sign, that is the child selector and is used to target "only" the following `li'`s after the `.Nav` `ul`, so we dont touch the submenu with that selector. Here is the fixed fiddle:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5enYP/1/. Modified quite a bit, just make sure to group all of the common text styles under your main container `.MenuTop`, this way you don't have to repeat them and also you can target your menu directly by using its own class, `.Nav`, so you don't need to target it again with the `.MenuTop ul` as you were before.

Comment: @Andres:  Thanks again.  I will analyze this to learn further.  I am fine with basic CSS, but this got a little deep as far as CSS goes.  I am more of a coding guy and do less with design/styling.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9V3KM/1) for you on jsFiddle.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#">Vehicles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

and the CSS:

```
nav ul {
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 25%;
}
nav a {
     font-family: Lucida Grande;
        background-color: #666666;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 3px 3px;

    display: block;
    font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


nav li ul {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1em;
    visibility: visible;

}
nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.cf:after, .cf:before {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}​
```

Comment: Did you happen to test this in anything but Chrome? It looks pretty bad in FF10.

Comment: No, but it could easily be adapted for cross-browser

Comment: I'm assuming this is code you're actually using somewhere and not something you wrote just for this answer, so you should definitely check it out in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/FBJAf/